# What does the line and load mean in this question?

Tags: circuit-analysis

### Here is the question

[image]

I don't need the answer, I just want to know what the line and load really represent here

Comment: They are clearly annotated under the circuit. Line and load are specific parts (set of connected elements) of the circuit.

Comment: When power input has a neutral (N) the other voltage is also called Line or L1. When split phase it’s called L1,L2, N. the arrows show the return of line, here shown without losses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The "line" represents the cables connecting the source to the load. It consists of the two horizontal sections between the red circles.
- The resistance and inductance is all represented on the upper line. I would expect that this is to simplify calculations and that in a real-world transmission line the impedance would be split across both.
- The load is the section to the right of the red circles, 15 Ω and -j10 Ω.

Comment: Got it. Thank you